# Detecting the destination URL when a visitor click to another domain

Tags: url, redirect, detect

I'd like to detect if a visitor clicks on a link on my web page which redirect visitor to another server. Is it possible detecting this? Should I do this tracking my gateway traffic?

Comment: you can probably achieve it using javascript and add a attribute onclick to the anchor. write a javascript function and called by the onlick and inside the function, just before user browser is redirect, send a request to yourself.

Comment: @Jasonw i have thought to do that, but there's a few different sources as web page. It won't be an easy operation. So i thought may be we can track it with any system script.

Comment: depend on how you design it. If you place that javascript function in a javascript file, and have the javascript file included in the html head section. Then this header html file is include for every webpages that you have. So for every links that you would like to get request, just call that general javascript function.